# Running azure Function blob trigger with APP service Plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-queues

I have a function in Azure Functions, which should be triggered when a new blob is added to Blob Container.

My Azure Function is connected to App service plan and have a such a host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
      "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:30",
      "batchSize": 16,
      "maxDequeueCount": 5,
      "newBatchThreshold": 8
    }
  }
}
```

I have scale out my app service plan (from one instance to 15 instance)

My expectation is now, that each 15 instances VMs should work simultaneously and process 24 (batchSize plus newBatchThreshold) files from blob at a time. Bu as I see in my Live Metrics Stream only 2 of 15 VMs are active and process my files?
by the way, I have enough files in my blobContainer (more than one million files). I mean I have enough load for VMs

My question is now, why another 13 VMs (instances) are Idle? What should I do to use the potential of all instances?

Comment: For your solution, I do recommend to use an Azure Event Grid **push** eventing model instead of the "legacy polling" BlobTrigger model of the Azure Function.

Comment: Those host.json settings are for a queue triggered function not a blob trigger?

Comment: @RomanKisscould you explain me alittle bit more about technical advantage of Event grid ageinst Azure Function

Comment: Have a look at more details of the BlobTrigger in the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#trigger---blob-receipts, Trigger - blob receipts, Trigger - poison blobs, Trigger - concurrency and memory usage, Trigger - polling and the **Warning note**

Comment: That link tells you nothing significant about blog triggers. What we need to know is why a blob trigger is not robust enough and why we should be using event grid instead.